# Handling dummy variables 2

Tags: list-manipulation, indexed-variable

This is a detailed exploration of my previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259360/handling-dummy-variables?noredirect=1#comment646831_259360),

There was some comment by @Nasser and @yarchik, I post my module in detail

```
J2[{\[Mu]_, \[Nu]_}, l : {___}] := 
 Module[{P, Q, R, n, m, \[Alpha], \[Beta], exp},
  P = l;
 n = Length[P];
 Q = Subsets[P, {1, n - 1}];
 R = Map[Complement[P, #] &, Q];
  m = Length[Q];
 exp = Sum[
J[{\[Mu], \[Alpha]}, Q[[i]]] J[{\[Nu], \[Alpha]}, 
R[[i]]], {i, 1, m}];
 ExpandAll[exp]
 ]
```

For given any list $l$, I define the product of JJ as J2.

For initial condition, it works fine but without initial condition

> J2[{[Mu], [Nu]}, {1, 2}]

produces

> J[{[Mu],[Alpha]$5288},{2}] J[{\[Nu],\[Alpha]$5288},{1}]+J[{\[Mu],\[Alpha]$5288},{1}] J[{\[Nu],\[Alpha]$5288},{2}]

How Can I remove $nnn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to pass in all variables that you want to part of the final result to the Module. Something like this

```
Clear["Global`*"]
J2[{μ_, ν_}, J_, α_, P : {___}] := Module[{Q, R, β, exp, i},
  Q = Subsets[P, {1, Length[P] - 1}];
  R = Map[Complement[P, #] &, Q];
  exp = Sum[J[{μ, α}, Q[[i]]]*J[{ν, α}, R[[i]]], {i, 1,Length[Q]}];
  ExpandAll[exp]
]
```

And now

```
J2[{μ, ν}, J, α, {1, 2}]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You also did not localize `i` and were using extra variables not needed so I removed those. For example, no need for `P` and `n` and `m`.  Also it looks like you are not using β anywhere inside the Module.

Btw, I think it would have been better to update your last question instead of making new question since it is on same subject.